# How do I fetch Authorization Code for AuthorizationCodeCredential when Creating GraphServiceClient?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, azure-ad-msal

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#authorization-code-provider it has a placeholder for "authorizationCode" and I am unsure where to get that from.

Update 6 July 2023:

I have been able to grab the Authorization Code from OnAccessCodeRecieved and I jam it into a Cookie:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"];
        options.TenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
        options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:CallbackPath"];
        options.Instance = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:Instance"];
        
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);
        options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{options.TenantId}";
        options.Scope.Add("user.read");
        var handler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
        
        options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator =
         AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(options.Authority).Validate;
        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("auth_code");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("code_verifier");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("auth_code", context.ProtocolMessage.Code);
            context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.TryGetValue("code_verifier", out string codeVerifier);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("code_verifier", codeVerifier);
            await handler(context);
        };
    })
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Then I construct the scope as followed:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphServiceClient>(provider =>
{
    var clientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
    var tenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
    var clientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"];
    var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var scheme = request.Scheme; // "http" or "https"
    var host = request.Host.Host; // host name (e.g., "localhost")
    var port = request.Host.Port; // port number

    var baseUrl = $"{scheme}://{host}";

    if (port != null)
    {
        baseUrl += $":{port}";
    }
    baseUrl += builder.Configuration["AzureAD:CallbackPath"];
    AuthorizationCodeCredential cred = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, request.Cookies["auth_code"], new AuthorizationCodeCredentialOptions()
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        RedirectUri = new Uri(baseUrl)
    });
    
    return new GraphServiceClient(cred, initialScopes, "https://graph.microsoft.com");
});
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
Unhandled exception in circuit '-UIvAsqM9hsCTeyHQDgVvmAmnQWbh8_cw9fktmi3w0k'.
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: AuthorizationCodeCredential authentication failed: AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE.

Which occurs on the Blazor call:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            user = await Graph.Me.GetAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

How do I pass the "code_verifier" to AuthorizationCodeCredential?

Comment: pls follow the official document to integrate Azure AD authentication/authorization. If you had a blazor WSAM app, it's a SPA, so you should go to the [SPA section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#single-page-applications), if what you have is a blazor server app, then go to web app section behind the SPA section.

Answer (score 0):

`Authorization Code` is used in auth code flow and can be generated when users sign in with their microsoft account, this code is used for generating access token.

When we test auth code flow out of code, we could compose a login request and test in the browser and getting the auth code.

But if we want to use auth code flow inside the application, we couldn't manually hardcode the login url and use code like `window.open(url)` to trigger the sign in process. We have to use builtin SDK or msal library instead.

For asp.net core web application, we can integrate auth code flow by using `Microsoft.Identity.Web`. You could find official sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-applications). Here's some code snippet. In Program.cs, it integrated microsoft identity in MVC project which would use auth code flow, then it also inject graph SDK so that we could use `graphClient` directly in Controller because it is already authorized.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
 .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()                
 .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
 .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
....
app.UseAuthentication();
...

using Microsoft.Graph;//version 4.43.0, using V5.x is different to use graphclient

[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    
    public HomeController( GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> testAsync() {
        var a = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am on Microsoft.Graph 5.16 and with that version GraphServiceClient requires manual setup from what I can tell. I have substantially updated the ticket