# Is Placing the AccessToken in a Cookie Sound? MSAL, Microsoft.Graph 5.16, Blazor

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have been attempting to get my GraphServiceClient for Microsoft.Graph 5.16 working through several iterations now. (see [How do I fetch Authorization Code for AuthorizationCodeCredential when Creating GraphServiceClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76614749/how-do-i-fetch-authorization-code-for-authorizationcodecredential-when-creating) and [Blazor + SignalR Core + Microsoft Identity Platform does not appear to authenticate on Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76600038/blazor-signalr-core-microsoft-identity-platform-does-not-appear-to-authentic) ) I have finally found something that seems to work, however I am concerned my use of storing the AccessToken in a Cookie might be insecure.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:ClientSecret"];
        options.TenantId = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:TenantId"];
        options.CallbackPath = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:CallbackPath"];
        options.Instance = builder.Configuration["AzureAD:Instance"];
        
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.Scope.Add(OidcConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);
        options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{options.TenantId}";
        options.Scope.Add("user.read");
        var handler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";
        
        options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator =
         AadIssuerValidator.GetAadIssuerValidator(options.Authority).Validate;
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("access_token");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
        };
    })
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccessTokenProvider, CookieTokenProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider>(provider =>
{
    return new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>());
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<GraphServiceClient>(provider =>
{
    
    return new GraphServiceClient(provider.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>());
});
```

CookieTokenProvider:

```
public class CookieTokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        protected IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor { get; }
        public CookieTokenProvider(IHttpContextAccessor contextAcessor) { 
            ContextAccessor = contextAcessor;
        }
        public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
        }

        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

This code works as expected, the only question is "is it secure?".